# Using Enumerable.OfType on list of Nullable<int> removes null items

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the code:

```
public class Foo : List<Nullable<int>> //could also say List<int?>
{
}

public void code()
{
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.Add(null);
  foo.Add(1);
  foo.Add(2);
  foo.Add(3);

  DoSerialize(foo);

}

void DoSerialize(object obj)
{
  Type type = obj.GetType();
  if (ReflectionUtils.DoesTypeSupportGenericInterface(type, typeof(IList<>)))
  {
    IList<object> arrayList = null;
    arrayList = ((IEnumerable)@obj).OfType<object>().ToList(); //problem line
    foreach (object element in arrayList)
    {
      Serialize(element);
    }
  }
}
```

The line with the //problem line comment is yielding unexpected results.
Within the `DoSerialize()` method, the obj variable is of type `Foo`, with 4 elements within it.
After the `ToList()` call, there are only 3 elements in it, the element containing the value null having been removed.

How can I convert a list of `Nullable<int>` or `<int?>` to a list of object and maintain the list cardinality at 4 with the null entry?

Comment: Side note: I've removed references to reflection from title/tags as your actual question is not related to reflection but rather to behavior of `OfType`. Feel free to improve/revert.

Comment: Why are you using the IList<object> anyways? Couldn't you just use the IEnumerable? `foreach (object element in ((IEnumerable)@obj))
    {
      Serialize(element);
    }
  }` The foreach is going to cast the list back to an IEnumerable anyways. Furthermore, the ToList() adds an extra loop over your items.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens foreach does not cast to IEnumerable.  Your suggestion is otherwise spot on.

Comment: @phoog, I think the ECMA 334 spec section 8.18 regarding foreach says this: "An iterator can be used as the body of a function member as long as the return type of the function member 
is one of the enumerator interfaces or one of the enumerable interfaces: 
• The enumerator interfaces are System.Collections.IEnumerator and types constructed from 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>. 
• The enumerable interfaces are System.Collections.IEnumerable and types constructed from 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>."

Comment: I remember it because I thought it strange that a language specification mention an specific interface.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens an "iterator" in that case is specifically a method that uses the yield keyword.  A type that implements either IEnumerable interface is not cast in a foreach.  A little-known fact is that implementing one of those interfaces is *not* a requirement for a type to be used in a foreach loop.

Comment: @phoog, I see. Is it enough to simply have the GetEnumerator() method?

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens no, there is an additional requirement that the GetEnumerator method return an instance of a type that has an appropriate MoveNext method and Current property (ecma spec 15.8.4, The foreach statement).  That section also explains that there *are* some circumstances in which the foreach *will* cast to IEnumerable.  If I read the spec correctly, though, if the collection is a `List<object>`, the collection type would be `List<object>` and there would be no cast to IEnumerable.

Comment: @phoog, I just tried this in Mono, and what do you know, it worked. As for the List-IEnum cast, I think I mis-spoke. It is not that it is cast, it is just that it is the IEnumerable members of List that will be used.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens Ah, but actually, they won't, because it will use `List<T>.GetEnumerator` which *doesn't* implement `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` because it returns an instance of the `List<T>.Enumerator` struct rather than a reference to `IEnumerator<T>`.  (This saves a heap allocation.)

Comment: @phoog, yep, looked it up and you are correct. In that case, I was just plain mistaken.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens the whole thing is rather confusing, and that's mostly because in the days before generic types, the language needed a way to iterate collections of value types without boxing them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Cast<object>` instead of `OfType<object>`.

```
var source = new List<int?> { 1, 2, null, 4 };

var castCount = ((IEnumerable)source).Cast<object>().Count();  // returns 4
var ofTypeCount = ((IEnumerable)source).OfType<object>().Count();   // return 3
```

That's because you cast your list to non-generic `IEnumerable`, so your `int?` is cast to `object` within `IEnumerator.Current` property. And `(int?)null` cast to `object` returns `null`. Then your `OfType<object>` performed `item is object` check, which for `null` returns `false`.

From *Immediete Window*:

```
((object)((int?)null))
null

null is object
false
```

Comment: This works. Good answer. Bare in mind that this little snippet of code is part of a large reflective xml serializer and deserializer which facilitates "reference tracking" and "cyclic dependency resolution" not called DataContractSerializer. Given my data set, null entry in a list cannot be discounted.

Comment: Why use `Cast<object>` if the objective is to use the collection in a foreach loop?  Casting to IEnumerable is sufficent.

Answer (score 0):

Credit where it's due; this was Phillip Scott Givens's suggestion.  I think it deserves to be posted with a code example.  I would add that you don't need ReflectionUtils here:

```
void DoSerialize(object obj)
{
  var enumerableObject = obj as IEnumerable;
  if (enumerableObject != null)
    foreach (object element in enumerableObject)
      Serialize(element);
}
```

Comment: Haha, yes, but I did not post as an answer because it does not answer the actual question, which is about why his nulls were being removed, but thanks for the credit.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens Actually his question was "how can I convert it to a List<object> without losing the nulls" and sometimes the best answer to a question is "you shouldn't be doing it that way in the first place."

Comment: again my bad, I was mislead by the title. "Using Enumerable.OfType on list of Nullable<int> removes null items".

Comment: What should i not be doing?  Granted theres a ton of other stuff going on that I did not add in my example because I figured it wouldnt result in a concise question. This is for a specific xml marshaller which does certain things if the object being serialized is a class or list or dictionary...and quite a cew other criteria.

Comment: @sbrett what should you not be doing?  That's an open question :) Phillip and I are just making suggestions for more concise, and marginally more efficent, code.  You're doing lots of work to determine what kind of `IList<T>` you are serializing, and then you enumerate the list, *cast each element to `object`*, and serialize each element.  If you rely on the fact that `IList<T>` inherits from the non-generic `IEnumerable`, you can save yourself all that work by just casting the object to IEnumerable.  That already returns the elements cast to `object` -- easy-peasy.